# Vue.js select last element within a div with pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am having an issue with Vue.js where I cannot select the last `<hr/>` tag in a div so that I can remove it.

My goal is to remove the last `<hr/>` tag in the div.

[Here is an example of the issue](https://codepen.io/Edon123/pen/wvBYoPM):

**JS**

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in list" class="exampleclass">
      <div>
      <button>btn {{i}}</button>
      </div>
      <input placeholder="sometext"></input>
      <hr /> // I want to remove the last instance of this element
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
hr {
  border-color:green;
}

/* 
  I want to display: none this last hr element, but I'm making it
  blue here for clarity of the issue. See the image below
*/
.exampleclass > hr:last-of-type {
  border-color:blue;
}
```

And here is the output of the following code:
[image]

As you can see, instead of only the last `<hr/>` element being blue, every element is blue. I've tried moving the class to a parent div, but I've had no success.

I was able to implement the correct behavior in vanilla javascript, which [you can see here](https://codepen.io/Edon123/pen/LYEJaOG). But for some reason I cannot get this to work in Vue.

How can I select the last `hr` element within a div, in Vue.js?

Comment: Please post relevant code here. Links may break and not everybody can follow them.

Comment: all relevant code is already included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not a Vue issue, but a matter of which elements your selector is acting on. The selector you're using is selecting the last `hr` element inside each element with the `.exampleclass` class. What you really want is the last `.exampleclass` element's `hr`.

You should be able to do that with the following:

```html
.exampleclass:last-of-type > hr {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Here's a complete sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <style>
      hr {
        border-color: green;
      }

      .exampleclass:last-of-type > hr{
        border-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="(item, i) in list" class="exampleclass">
        <div>
        <button>btn {{i}}</button>
        </div>
        <input placeholder="sometext"> {{ item }} </input>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        list: ['itemOne', 'itemTwo', 'itemThree']
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `v-if` to the `hr` and in that check whether it's the last:

`<hr v-if="i !== list.length - 1" />`

Comment: that would fix it, however, I'm trying to solve this with psuedo selectors, they seem like a cleaner solution to me. I appreciate your help though

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `:last-of-type` on wrong element. Because every `.exampleClass` have only one `hr` and there are multiple elements with class `exampleClass`.
So you should do it like this:

```
.exampleClass:last-of-type > hr {
  border-color: blue
}
```